# How to use raw data from get_the_content() as a variable

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am trying to use the content to signify which template_part code to load on my page. For example, if the `content == "volume"` I want to load `get_template_part('lib/volume')`;

```
<?php
    $content = get_the_content();       
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);
    $content = filter_var($content, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    get_template_part('lib/'.$content); 
?>
```

This is the code in my template, however it doesn't load the desired template part.

Comment: Please give us more information about the problem - just saying its not working doesn't give us much to go on. Have you checked to see what the value of `$content` is before and after you have stripped & filtered it? That will give you an idea of what is wrong so we can tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip all html tags with using `wp_strip_all_tags()` to get only the content. `strip_tags()` won't help you get rid of comments and wordpress gives us the great function to also delete the script and style.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

So you can use one line of code to get a clean content:

```
$content = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );
```

Maybe this is the reason. Have you tried so display the value of `$content` to make sure you have the string you want to have? If it outputs the string the right way, there might be a problem with the `get_template_part()` function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

You can try putting the string together, before using in the function:

```
$content = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );
$content = "lib/".$content;
get_template_part( $content );
```

If this is not working, check the name of the folder `lib` (has to be subfolder in the root of your theme folder) and the name of your php files. It could also be possible that there is something wrong with the template part file and that is the reason it is not loaded. Next check the page template inside of which you are trying to get the template part.

If nothing helps you out, it could be an alternative using `include()` instead of `get_template_part()`.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! The wp_strip_all_tags worked for me. I think earlier the comments were still there which is why I couldn't use get_template_part.